# What is the best way to measure the relationship between a baseball player's performance and salary (using statistics)?

Tags: database, sql

Good afternoon,

In an effort to learn more about statistics and SQL programming and possibly start building a project portfolio for myself, I've taken it upon myself to investigate a particular problem in Major League Baseball: maximizing performance while minimizing costs. If that sounds familiar, it's probably because you have some knowledge of the 2011 film Moneyball and/or the real-life story that inspired it.

I've looked into the problem quite a bit over the last few days, but it's been a while since I've taken a statistics course so I'm wondering if my methods are sound or need some improvement.

The first step was to evaluate what a "good" player is. I decided to use look at the entire pool of players for a certain year (in this case, 2016, which was the most recent year that I salary data for). Using the [Sean Lahman Baseball Database](https://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/) (a massive database containing countless baseball statistics going back to the earliest days of the sport), and MySQL, I filtered a list of MLB players in the year 2016, a select few statistics that I would use to measure performance, and their salary. I also filtered the list to only include players that had 200 or more At Bats, as the data could be easily skewed by players who had, for instance, a handful of ABs but also overperformed in their minimal time on the field. With this data pool, I decided that I was going to create a new statistic that I called Aggregate Ability (AA) that would combine six other statistics into a single number. I have no idea if this makes any mathematical sense, which is another reason why I wanted to ask this question here.

Basically, AA takes Batting Average, On-Base Percentage, Slugging Percentage, On-Base-Plus-Slugging, Weighted On-Base Average, and Weighted Runs Created and meshed them together into a single stat, based on the league average of all six individual stats. If a player's AVG, OBP, SLG, OPS, wOBA and wRC were each *identical to the league average*, their AA would be equal to 100. Any value under 100 means the player underperformed, and any value over 100 means the player overperformed.

This brings us to the meat of the experiment: now I created a variety of scatterplots correlating AA and Annual Salary to see if there's any relationship. Specifically, I looked at the top 30% of salaries and the bottom 30% of salaries, with the hypothesis in mind that a player's salary doesn't guarantee a higher AA stat, and therefore there will be a weak correlation between the two numbers.

As it turned out, this hypothesis was correct- for both types of players. The highest paid and lowest paid players had correlations of 0.20 and 0.22, respectively - obviously a very weak correlation. I then tested the correlation with the players and the individual statistics and still found very weak correlations.

My next step was to expand the data pool, so I re-filtered the list in MySQL to include every player between 1985 and 2015 with at least 200 ABs. I then re-evaluated this new pool, this time not taking salary percentiles into consideration. I simply took every single player, ranging in salary from less than 100,000 to over 30,000,000, and looked at how their salary related to their AA. The correlation was 0.31, still remarkably weak.

At this point I'm starting to think that, based on my data and methodology, that there is not a correlation between a player's ability and salary. However, there are a couple of questions I have. Keep in mind that I'm about as much of an amateur as I can be, so please go easy on me!

Firstly, is the AA stat good or bad? Is it a poorly constructed metric that is a bad way of measuring overall performance or not?

Secondly, is my methodology acceptable or are my methods completely wrong?

I'm open to any and all recommendations. Again, this is just a fun project that has no real-world significance, but I would like to one day work with data and statistics for a living so any practice is helpful.

Thank you!